# Pandas: Access to cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add my dataframes cell value to a dictionary but the outcome is not what I'm expecting to get.

Am I querying the pandas in a wrong way ?

```
df[df.Equipment==key].InstImoNoTrim.iloc[0]

{'GB': 50    0.0
 Name: dailyaverage, dtype: float64}
```

While the expected result is :

```
{'GB':  0.0}
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome?

Comment: What you've presented is not consistent with anything I can think of unless you have dictionaries in your dataframe cells.  Please include your data and read this to get a better idea of how to ask questions [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [**HowToAsk**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a multindex on your columns, I think you need a further level of indexing i.e.:

```
df[df.Equipment==key].InstImoNoTrim.dailyaverage
```